# Convert empty string into Null to save Null Values into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I just read out very nice answers to save null into database column using

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.tex) ? (object)textbox.text: DBNull.Value;
```

or using

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("foo",
    foo == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)foo);
```

and I tried with others too but it's not working for me as I am not very expert of C# language but I must want to save null into my SQL Server database column.

Here is my code which I tried to save null value but it sends empty string which is not my requirement.

```
oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate4 = Convert.ToString(DBNull.Value);
```

So when I write

```
oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate4 = null;
```

it gives me error that my procedure wants parameter which was not supplied but I know that I have supplied null to it.

When I write

```
oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate4=Convert.ToString(DBNull.Value);
```

it saves the empty string in my database column but I need a `null` value there.

When I manually save null values in stored procedure it accepts null and save null but why it is not accepting

```
oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate4 = null;
```

from my C# code?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what exactly is oCourseRegistrationPaypal?

Comment: Dont convert `DBNull.Value` to object. Save it directly.

Comment: @attila its object of my custom type layer and i want to store null in this object and then i  pass this object to data access layer where i have written down the saving procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert a `DBNull.Value` to a string, it's gonna give you an empty string.

Just store a `DBNull.Value`.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("foo",
    foo == null ? DBNull.Value : foo);
```

or alternatively:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("foo",
    foo ?? DBNull.Value);
```

EDIT: Per your edit to your question, replace `foo` with `oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate4`. The code I pasted above will replace `null` with `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: when i try to save oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate2 = DBNull.Value;
it gives me error that cant conver dbnull to string.

Comment: Because DBNull.Value is not a string.

Comment: I dont want to save null using sql parameters etc but i just want to save null in oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate2 ?
is that possible?

Comment: Yes, `oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate2 = null`.

Comment: so what should i do ? 
let me update my question to understand it.

Comment: Sounds like you might be confusing `null` with `DBNull`. The latter is used to specify null as a SQL/db parameter. The former is used just about everywhere else to represent null.

Comment: okay so can you tell me how to do it with this 
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt_UserTTrainingDate1", oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate1 == null ? DBNull.Value:);

Comment: I showed you how to do it in my answer. Replace `foo` with `oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate4` in my answer code.

Comment: its giving me error that if i replace according to your answer.

Comment: What are you putting exactly and what error are you getting?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt_UserTTrainingDate1", oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate1 == null ? DBNull.Value : oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate1);

it gives error that "Type of conditional expression cant be determind becuase there is no conversion b/w System.DBnull and string"

Comment: What about `oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate1 == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)oCourseRegistrationPaypal.UserTheoryTrainingDate1`?

Comment: its saving empty string but not null.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the `AddWithValue()` sample that you saw: it forces ADO.Net to *guess* at the database type for the parameter. Often it will guess right, but sometimes it guesses wrong.

The good news it that it guesses okay most of the them, and even when it guesses wrong code still tends to work. However, very rarely, this will cause your code to blow up and throw an exception. A more common problem is that this will cause your database to need per-row conversions, or break an index use. It can take a query that returns instantly in testing and make it run for several minutes in production.

The problem is worse when combined with the conditional operator check, because it forces you to cast both sides to `Object`. This removes the most important hint that ADO.Net gets when guessing the database type. Instead of a string, Datetime, Double, etc, all ADO.Net gets to see is "Object" as the .Net type. This makes it much more likely to guess the wrong database type. If this is your go-to pattern for adding NULLs, the result is sub-optimal performance throughout your application.

Instead, I like to do this:

```
//explicit DB type, and don't worry about DBNull just yet
cmd.Parameters.Add("foo",  SqlDbType.Int).Value = foo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("bar", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = bar;
//if you have more parameters, add them all this way

// after all parameters are added:
foreach(var p in cmd.Parameters.Where(p => p.Value == null))
{
    p.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

There is one caveat here: value types like int and DateTime will never match that condition, and so my actual code has to a little more complicated (involving `Nullable<T>`s). But hopefully it gives you the right idea.